# Strike a String though JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

In my `if`/`else` statement, instead of having:

```
todoTextWithCompletion = '(x) ' + todo.todoText;
```

I want to display a strike string (`todo.todoText input`) in the DOM. I've tried replacing it to

```
todoTextWithCompletion = todo.todoText.strike();
```

But it's displaying `<strike>todo.todoText</strike>` in the DOM.

```
displayTodos: function () {
var todosUl = document.querySelector('ul');
todosUl.innerHTML = '';

todoList.todos.forEach(function (todo, position) {
  var todoLi = document.createElement('li');
  var todoTextWithCompletion = '';

  if (todo.completed === true) {
    todoTextWithCompletion = '(x) ' + todo.todoText;
  } else {
    todoTextWithCompletion = '( ) ' + todo.todoText;
  }

  todoLi.id = position;
  todoLi.textContent = todoTextWithCompletion;
  todoLi.appendChild(this.createToggleButton());
  todoLi.appendChild(this.createDeleteButton());
  todosUl.appendChild(todoLi);
}, this);
},
```

Comment: You can use CSS for that: `text-decoration: line-through;`

Comment: You're using `textContent` instead of `innerHTML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also style your text content using JavaScript.

Assuming `todoLi` is the element you want to strike-through:

```
todoLi.style.textDecoration = "line-through";
```

Using the new [CSS Typed Object Model](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/cssom), this will be:

```
todoLi.attributeStyleMap.set('text-decoration', 'line-through');
```

Both will have the same effect as if you're applying the `text-decoration: line-through;` property using CSS.

Also keep in mind that The `<strike>` tag is **not supported in HTML5**.

Use `<del>` or `<s>` instead.

Comment: Note that using the new CSS Typed Object Model this will be: `todoLi.attributeStyleMap.set('text-decoration', 'line-through');` See Eric Bidelman's piece from March 2018: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/cssom

Comment: Thanks, answer updated. (I am looking forward to try the `attributeStyleMap`)

Answer (score 0):

You are setting [`textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent#Differences_from_innerHTML) to an HTML string.  `textContent` is not parsed as HTML, it is added as plain text:

> Differences from innerHTML
>
> Element.innerHTML returns HTML as its name indicates. Sometimes people
>   use innerHTML to retrieve or write text inside an element. textContent
>   has better performance because its value is not parsed as HTML.
>   Moreover, using textContent can prevent XSS attacks.

Instead, you should construct the `<strike>` node using `document.createElement("strike");`, use `innerHTML`, or as U-ways suggested, add the `text-decoration: line-through` CSS style.

```js
document.getElementById("text-content").textContent = "<strike>foo</strike>"
document.getElementById("inner-html").innerHTML = "<strike>foo</strike>"
```

```html
<div id="text-content"></div>
<div id="inner-html"></div>
```

Comment: Thank You zero298, Your answer seems great too. But, I  've got a little confused with all the details you provided. I'm still learning all the terms. I appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Rather than adding a raw style to the element, you can add a class using the `classList API`:

**CSS**

```
.item-completed {
text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

**Javascript**

```
var todoLi = document.createElement('li');

if (todo.completed === true) {

    todoLi.classList.add('item-completed');
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rounin! Your answer is helpful too! Add a class and keeping all the style in the CSS file seems a smart way to go! I appreciate it!

Comment: You're welcome. As a general rule of thumb (it's not always possible) I tend to keep all styles in the stylesheet and add or subtract classes to the DOM, rather than adding and subtracting raw styles. In this instance, there's no real difference, but in cases where the `class` contains a number of style declarations, it's much more practical and concise.